# At -q not queuing

Tags: scheduling, at

I am using Ubuntu server. I have the following at command:

```
at -q a now
```

I expected that the `-q a` would cause the commands to run sequentially, but they are not. On inspection with `atq` they are all designated the `=` queue meaning that the commands are not being queued rather are all running as soon as they are sent to at.

How can I make them run sequentially?

Edit: I am specifically asking if this can be achieved with the at command?

Comment: Write your commands as a shell script and then submit the shell script as an `at` job.

Comment: I can't do that because different commands are run and different times.

Comment: Then you need to modify your question to more clearly explain what are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I have edited the question.

Comment: You can specify an alternative queue, and in the definition put a limit to number of concurent jobs.

Comment: Can you explain how I set the limit to 1?